# C# is there an easy way to get into TCP Socket Programming?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I've worked on a program that uses databases to send small messages from one PC to another. What I've done is put the database in a shared folder, have the program on the other PC connect to it (via a Path, no less), and there it is, a simple and easy way to get messages to and fro PCs on a network. Not the best option, but it's just homework, and the quick and dirty approach got me a grade.

But now the homework is done, and I'd like to improve upon what I did. The problem with the program is in the deployment stage. There are too many folders / installation paths and administrative / sharing issues regarding pathing directly to a database on a shared folder.

So the good folks here in stackoverflow advised me to try Socket Programming, which I think is a bit out of my league. But you never know...

Also, I'm aware of the difference between Sync and Async socket programming. One blocks, the other doesn't. The program I'm working on is a simple turn-based game, so I thought Synchronous might be good enough, since if it's not your turn, you really can't do anything. The issue however is that the program is treated as "not responding". I tried asynchronous, but ran into problems with threading, something I consider WAY out of my league.

Logically, the program is simple. One host, one client. Upon client connection, host sends data. Then client receives, send out its own data. And so on, until one player loses.

I'm sorry to say only .NET 2.0 is installed in my school. No WCF or anything. Also, it must be done in C# Windows Forms, so XNA is out.

So, I'd like to ask... is there an easy way to get into Socket Programming? Any guides / sample projects that can help? Pre-made codes that can be studied, and adapted?

Majority of the samples I found and adapted are chat applications, which I thought good enough, but making it modular simply breaks it.

Comment: Read the documentation of the [`System.Net.Sockets`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb27wehh.aspx) namespace.

Comment: If you are struggling with the complexities of threading checkout the BackgroundWorker class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx it simplifies things somewhat

Comment: There is another option you may consider: non-blocking sockets, which allow you to poll for incoming data on the "current thread". It may cost a tiny bit of performance, but I doubt any of the players would notice.

Comment: Only .NET 2.0 on your school? I hate seeying schools not preparing their students for whats out there....

Comment: +1 for coming back to learn how to do it in a less "insane" way!

Comment: Yes, well, the first reply to my previous question was "What you're doing is insane!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chat application examples you encountered should be enough. It is not clear to me what you refer to as "making it modular".

What you need is to design a protocol to be sent over the connection, an agreement of rules so to say, so that one knows what the other is talking about. So instead of sending plain text (chat) you can send the following:
0x03 (length of the message) 
0x0A (move command in this fictional protocol)
0x02 (parameter 1 of the command, X coordinate in this case, it's all defined in the protocol design)
0x05 (parameter 2 of the command, Y coordinate in this case, it's all defined in the protocol design)

Now it's entirely up to you what happens after you received and interpreted the data. Personally I would go for the Async solution, since it leaves your program to do other stuff (graphics?). And it's more easily adaptable in code, in my experience.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clear up the 'modular' part. I thought it would be too long. See, the chat application I studied and adapted uses Async, I believe. That, I can understand. It's relatively straightforward. However, my program calls several functions before sending and after receiving strings, functions that apply GUI changes based on the received strings, as well as modify what strings to send, based on what was pressed on the GUI. It is there where the program (mostly threading) fails.

Comment: So you need control on when you receive the messages. This can be done by implementing a Queue of a class Message, where Message contains the data interpreted by you in the callback. So each callback you parse the incoming messages and queue them. Then when the time has come to look if any messages have been received, you can simply look them up in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some classes which can be used to transport objects over a socket using the `BinaryFormatter`.

Here are some tests for my `BinaryTransport` class:

http://fadd.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/67972#1055425

The actual class:

http://fadd.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/67972#1054822

Do note that it's a while ago that I wrote them. I just noticed some small bugs. But either use them or just study the classes to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

I remember when I started with socket communication in C# I tried to implement a simple chat program between a client and a server and then between multiple clients. Here is the tutorial that I was reading then: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/TCPIPChat.aspx

If you want the full code I can upload my final project and you can study the code. It also uses multithreading so you can see how to handle this situation in GUI applications.

Side note: Wow, that database idea is the craziest thing I've seen in terms of PC-to-PC communication. Well done!

Comment: I based my program on a chat application as well, although my success was rather limited. What kind of project were you working on?

Comment: It was also a chat application but with a server routing messages between multiple clients.

Answer (score 0):

One interesting, useful and easy exercise you can do to learn about sockets (which C# makes it easier even) was creating a TCP-based logger.

During development every programmer needs a way to know what's happening under the hood at certain points. Without a logger you would normally write something like:

```
Console.WriteLine( "blah" );
```

which results in a dull, unfiltered, unorganized string thrown to the output window.

I created a TCP-based logger very easily using sockets. In one hand you have a separate Winforms application (the server), which is in charge of listening to incoming messages and beautifully displaying them on a rich-content control. In the other hand, you write a very simple class (the client) with a single function like:

```
public static class MyConsole
{
    public static void WriteLine( string message, string whatever )
    {
        // send to the net
        if( mTcpSocket.Connected )
            mTcpSocket.Send( message );

        // in case the server is not there we still have regular output
        Console.WriteLine( message );
    }
}
```

I created this logger once and have been using it ever since. Furthermore, given its tcp nature, with minor changes on the server side I've been successfully using it from different languages, as C# and Java, and now using it from ActionScript.